# la cadena no tiene formato correcto c#

Tags: c#

```
string query = "insert into Facturacion (Codigo,Producto,PrecioxUnidad,Cantidad,Descuento"+
                   ",Cliente,DescuentoCliente,MontoTotal,NumFactura)" + " values ('" + fact.Codigo + "', '" + fact.Producto + "'," +
                   "" + Convert.ToDouble(fact.PrecioxUnidad) + "," + Convert.ToInt32(fact.Cantidad) + "," + Convert.ToDouble(fact.Descuento) + "," +
                   "'" + fact.Cliente + "'," + Convert.ToDouble(fact.Clientedesc) + "," +
                   "" + Convert.ToDouble(fact.Total) + "," + Convert.ToInt32(fact.NFactura) + ")";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Podrías añadir a tu pregunta cómo queda tu cadena _query_ una vez hechas las concatenaciones.

Comment: Me parece a simple viste que le puede faltar algun espacio luego de la , en los values.

Comment: Te recomiendo que en vez de string uses la clase StringBuilder, en este caso te va a facilitar el trabajo

Comment: La forma con la cual construyes la query es muy poco fiable. Utiliza parámetros y evitarás problemas de seguridad y errores.
Si fact.producto contiene un ' la query te falla.

Comment: Probablemente el error esté en alguno de los `Conver.tToDouble` que tienes, si está lelgando algun valor que no puede convertirse en `double`. De todas maneras, como bien dice @CarmineM. no se debe usar nunca concatenación de cadenas para montar una query, sino [consultas parametrizadas](https://blogs.msmvps.com/otelis/2007/06/04/par-225-metros-de-sqlcommand-y-las-variables-de-sql-server/)